# Can an air-intake fan stop smoke wafting through a brick common wall?

Tags: intake-fan

It shouldn't happen but it does. The house next door to a friend's semi-detached house burned. It wasn't a big fire but smoke wafted through the common brick wall, particularly along the joists. And that turned out to occasion a lot of damage in our friend's house.

These stone-houses are over 130 years old. And, short of lifting the floors along the common brick wall, which would in turn require major work, there does not seem anything that can be done to make the common brick wall airtight.

We live in the same kind of semi-detached a few houses away and I started wondering if having an intake fan that would create a slight over-pressure in the house might not be enough to prevent the smoke from wafting across the common wall.

The questions then would be:

1. What kind of fan? E.g. air-flow versus high-pressure?
2. How to size the fan? E.g. in relation to the volume of the house or in relation to the area of the common wall?
3. Where to locate the fan? (Assuming all outside doors and all windows are closed and all inside doors are open.) Most convenient in our case would be the basement. But another plus would be to confine the unavoidable air flow and just let the pressure build up in the rest of the house.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? And by "semi-detached house" do you mean a duplex (2 units separated by a party wall in 1 structure), or a townhome (3 or more units separated by party walls)?

Comment: You would have to keep all your doors and windows closed.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Philadelphia. Don't know the language. Here they call it semi-detached. Probably because they were built to look like a single detached house if you didn't look too hard. Anyway, the two "units" sit side by side, completely separate, with, inside, a four-layer brick wall.

Comment: @A.I. Brevelen The idea would be, should we suddenly see or smell smoke wafting from across the common wall, indeed to close the entrance doors and the windows, open all inside doors and turn on the fan.

Comment: From where would you draw fresh air for the intake fan?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone The basement has a window on the backyard. Very clean air. And since the two semi-detached are back to back, away from the other one.

Comment: It should be automated. - Picture this: your house is festooned with smoke and flame detectors pointed at your semi-attached neihbor. At the first sign of a conflagration, a piercing alarm sounds in your bedroom; great motors and solenoids slam shut all your doors, vents, and windows; the weather cover is ejected from your blower intake; and your house is pressurized to 2.5 psi. - Of course, you'll have to rig a safety harness before you open your front door, or else you'll be blown across the street.

Comment: @schremmer -- duplex to the rest of us then.  There don't seem to be any Code requirements on smoke control itself when it comes to party wall performance, but I don't think the IRC really forsees active smoke control in a dwelling unit, either, which is what this is.  In fact, I'd say that this'd kick you into IBC/IFC territory, which is a fair bit more complicated (active smoke control systems are normally found in malls, theaters/auditoriums, and other places of assembly)

Comment: @schremmer -- also, most active smoke control is designed for life-safety (to provide tenable evac conditions), not property preservation (which is the application you're envisioning). This may be best fixed by fixing the party wall, even though that will be quite a bit of work...

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Before "it" can be automated, "it" ought to be defined and to exist. And, by the way, judging from the way I saw smoke wafting at out friend's house, I would have thought that 2.6 psi would be overdoing it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel This is not about standard "active smoke control" but the three specific questions I asked above. No more. In other words, I am not thinking of "life safety" as we have smoke detectors. Just, as I explained at the outset, I just want to prevent smoke from wafting in due to a slight pressure differential.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I got curious and searched for the "difference between semi-detached and duplex". There is one.

Comment: @schremmer -- can we have some more construction details on the party walls in question btw, especially how the joists attach to them?  Also, are the exterior walls also multi-wythe brick?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel There is NO WAY I can get at the common wall. Let alone the joists. They are sitting in pockets in the two layers on our side of the brick wall. Outside wall is stone. **Please, let us stay with the intake fan.**

Answer (score 0):

### The firefighters won't be fans of your proposed fan

Here's the rub -- your fan will need to be running while the neighboring unit is burning to do much.  Thing is, putting a positive pressure on one side of a leaky firewall while a fire is burning on the other will keep smoke from getting into the non-burning compartment, but it will also *blow fresh air into the burning compartment* in the process.

This can (and likely will) cause the fire to do things firefighters aren't expecting it to do if they don't know what's going on (and how would they?).  At the very least, it has the strong potential to interfere with how the firefighters are ventilating the fire structure *themselves* to manage what the fire is doing while they are in the process of taking it down.  Worst case, this sort of thing winds up getting written up in a NIOSH report.

Comment: You are absolutely right of course and this is precisely the reason I asked the question. The fan ought to override the pressure next door but _just a tiny little bit_. I am friendly with my neighbor so I will be able to check if the fan is creating any airflow---which it should not. But, before I get to that, I need to have an idea of how to compute the size of the fan which probably should be rather small. But how small is small?

Comment: Ok. I must confess being turned off by the first paragraph in your answer in that, as I said, I precisely do _not_ want to "_blow fresh air_" next door and just want to _balance the over-pressure_. But I missed, and did not know, that firefighters might be "_ventilating the fire structure_". With fans? Could it be that which caused the smoke to waft in? If so, what pressure might they have created?  But in fact I was watching and didn't notice any ventilating equipment. What they did was simply to break all the windows.

Comment: @schremmer -- part of how they decide which windows to break is by where they want air to enter the fireground (think "passive ventilation"); however, in some situations, firefighters *will* use fans to ventilate a structure ("positive pressure ventilation" is the term).  This is *atop* any pressure differentials created as a result of the temperature-induced air drive from the fire itself (i.e. stack effect in overdrive, etc)